# how to disable main menu using javascript in sub pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable main menu item in sub page using it's id. Tried "`setAttribute`" and "`disabled`" options.

```
document.getElementById("bloc_menu:j_id14").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
document.getElementById("bloc_menu:j_id14").disabled = true;
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thank u.

Comment: share your demo with element `bloc_menu:j_id14` which is not working

Comment: The `disabled` attribute only works on a couple of elements, all of which are related to forms. A menu is usually not a form, so I wonder what your actual HTML looks like.

Comment: What type of element is `document.getElementById("bloc_menu:j_id14")`? I'm guessing it doesn't support the `disabled` property

Comment: @Rishi<div id="bloc_menu3">

  <ul class="sf-menu">
   <h:form id="bloc_menu">
    <li id="li1"><a4j:commandLink value="#{label.ecran_corbeille}"
      actionListener="#{queuesBean.resetQueuesListener}"
      action="/queues/queues"
      rendered="#{securityBean.corbeilleAccess and queuesBean.initOk}"
      onclick="this.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');" /></li></h:form>
  </ul>
 </div>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a list

Comment: ID can't have ":" colon

Comment: @vi5ion thanks for the information

Comment: @Shiladitya in HTML5 they can

Comment: @Shiladitya because the list item in another page.

Comment: @JayakrishnanAP that's your issue then. `ul` elements do not support the `disabled` property. You will need to find another mechanism to prevent whatever behaviour you're attempting

Comment: Guys I just want to disable the main menu item in sub page using its id or div id. Please give me one solution. Thank you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to do or why you can't handle this serverside, but I've made a little example of a simple menu that can be disabled/enabled.

```js
var $mainMenu, $links;

$(function() {
  $mainMenu = $('#main-menu');
  $links = $mainMenu.find('.menu-item__link').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    $link.data('href', $link.attr('href'));
  });
  $('#toggle-main-menu').on('click', function() {
    toggleMainMenu();
  });
});

function toggleMainMenu() {
  if ($mainMenu.hasClass('disabled')) {
    $mainMenu.removeClass('disabled');
    restoreLinks();
  }
  else {
    $mainMenu.addClass('disabled');
    removeLinks();
  }
}

function removeLinks() {
  $links.removeAttr('href');
}

function restoreLinks() {
  $links.each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    $link.attr('href', $link.data('href'));
  });
}
```

```css
#main-menu .menu-item__link {
  color: #000;
}

#main-menu.disabled .menu-item__link {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-item__link" href="#someLink1">Some link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-item__link" href="#someLink2">Some link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-item__link" href="#someLink3">Some link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="toggle-main-menu">Toggle the menu</button>
```

Comment: For me it's worked with simple code.document.getElementById("bloc_menu:j_id14").style.pointerEvents = 'none';

Comment: That only works for mouse events. If you tab to your link and hit `Enter` on your keyboard you will still be able to trigger the link.

Comment: with change focus we can manage that. thank you for your comments.